# Magento Multistore and ZenCart configuration?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, configuration

I have a unique situation that I haven't been able to find the answer to.

I have a **Magento 1.9x** install with a store on it.  Let's call it `store1.com`.  I have a second store installed using **ZenCart** and that is `store2.com`.  I want to create a NEW store using Magento Multistore option.  I've gone through all the correct steps and I know it's right.

My question is: how do I preview my new multistore BEFORE I update the **DNS** for `ZenCart store2.com` to point to Magento so that I can start working on the design?

`Store2.com` is currently live on ZenCart and I am not ready to update the URL.